# why the certificateVerifierTask_class is not unload in netty-tcnative

Tags: openssl, netty, boringssl

when I read the source [sslcontext.c](https://github.com/netty/netty-tcnative/blob/main/openssl-dynamic/src/main/c/sslcontext.c) of netty-tcnative, I found that the 「certificateVerifierTask_class」 is loaded in　the method 　「netty_internal_tcnative_SSLContext_JNI_OnLoad」

```
jint netty_internal_tcnative_SSLContext_JNI_OnLoad(JNIEnv* env, const char* packagePrefix) {

  .....

    NETTY_JNI_UTIL_PREPEND(packagePrefix, "io/netty/internal/tcnative/CertificateVerifierTask", name, error);
    NETTY_JNI_UTIL_LOAD_CLASS(env, certificateVerifierTask_class, name, error);
  
    NETTY_JNI_UTIL_PREPEND(packagePrefix, "io/netty/internal/tcnative/CertificateVerifier;)V", name, error);
    NETTY_JNI_UTIL_PREPEND("(J[[BLjava/lang/String;L", name, combinedName, error);
    TCN_REASSIGN(name, combinedName);
    NETTY_JNI_UTIL_GET_METHOD(env, certificateVerifierTask_class, certificateVerifierTask_init, "<init>", name, error);
 
  .....

}
```

but in method 「netty_internal_tcnative_SSLContext_JNI_OnUnLoad」, this class is not unload.

```
void netty_internal_tcnative_SSLContext_JNI_OnUnLoad(JNIEnv* env, const char* packagePrefix) {
    NETTY_JNI_UTIL_UNLOAD_CLASS(env, sslTask_class);
    NETTY_JNI_UTIL_UNLOAD_CLASS(env, certificateCallbackTask_class);
    NETTY_JNI_UTIL_UNLOAD_CLASS(env, sslPrivateKeyMethodTask_class);
    NETTY_JNI_UTIL_UNLOAD_CLASS(env, sslPrivateKeyMethodSignTask_class);
    NETTY_JNI_UTIL_UNLOAD_CLASS(env, sslPrivateKeyMethodDecryptTask_class);

    netty_jni_util_unregister_natives(env, packagePrefix, SSLCONTEXT_CLASSNAME);
}
```

is the unload process unnecessary?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a bug... Thanks a lot I just fixed it https://github.com/netty/netty-tcnative/pull/637